# How to find out the list of all IP addresses which accesses a EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

How to find out the list of all IP addresses which accesses a EC2 instance in a certain day using ssh protocol. Is there a way to get this information, we would need this for audit purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Try the command:

```
[pinky][1]
```

You'll get something like this:

```
Login      Name                 TTY    Idle   When                 Where 

root       root                 pts/0         2009-06-15 13:41     192.168.1.133
```

Comment: Thanks @Lostsoul. http://linux.die.net/man/1/pinky. Is there a way to do this for an entire month or any year? How do you do this on Amazon EC2 Windows 2008 instance.

Comment: @Joe Sorry, I thought you were using *nix.  I do not use windows so I'm not really sure but are you using some kind of third party ssh server? Could there be some loggings there? or if your using some kind of built in windows ssh would the standard windows logging capture this information?